# Javascript file charset in ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems with latin characters in .js files (they are shown incorrectly in the HTML). The only way to make the scripts work is by adding the charset attribute:

```
<script src="js/Controllers/MyController.js" charset="iso-8859-1"></script>
```

If there any to force this in Web.Config?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use utf-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a "problem" with the way the file is saved. It is probably saved as UTF-8 "with signature" and the browser is trying to interpret it as such, when you not set the `charset` attribute. The page is probably not UTF-8, so, there is a mismatch.

Try to save this as "Wester European (Windows)" encoding - this should be a simple ASCII text file then. To do this in VS go to "Save As" dialog and select "Save with Encoding".

Or, it could be the other way around, but definitely it looks like there is a mismatch between the page encoding and the JS file encoding.